# Remove shipping estimate message on cart table in Woocommerce 3.5

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, woocommerce, cart

In the latest release of WooCommerce, there is a message being displayed in the cart stating the shipping cost is only an estimate.

[image: https://www.screencast.com/t/2hSd7B27I]

This doesn't make any sense when someone is using flat rate shipping and does not calculate shipping at all. Note, I don't have calculated shipping activated either. I tried to hide the message with css, however it of course, does not have a class to target.

Does anyone know how to turn this off?

Answer (score 7):

Now you can use `woocommerce_shipping_estimate_html` filter.

Eg.:

```
function shipping_estimate_html()
{
    return null;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_shipping_estimate_html', 'shipping_estimate_html');
```

Answer (score 4):

This is something new since Woocommerce version 3.5: You will need to [override via your theme *(as explained on this link)* the template](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/) file [`cart/cart-shipping.php`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/release/3.5/templates/cart/cart-shipping.php).

From line **`46`** to **`58`**, you will replace the following:

```
<?php if ( is_cart() ) : ?>
    <p class="woocommerce-shipping-destination">
        <?php
        if ( $formatted_destination ) {
            // Translators: $s shipping destination.
            printf( esc_html__( 'Estimate for %s.', 'woocommerce' ) . ' ', '<strong>' . esc_html( $formatted_destination ) . '</strong>' );
            $calculator_text = __( 'Change address', 'woocommerce' );
        } else {
            echo esc_html__( 'This is only an estimate. Prices will be updated during checkout.', 'woocommerce' );
        }
        ?>
    </p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

By this:

```
<?php if ( is_cart() ) : ?>
    <p class="woocommerce-shipping-destination">
        <?php
        if ( $formatted_destination ) {
            $calculator_text = __( 'Change address', 'woocommerce' );
        }
        ?>
    </p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

You are done… No more annoying notices.

Answer (score 2):

In the event your Template doesn't have a cart-shipping.php file, this css modification worked for me:

```
.cart-totals-inner .woocommerce-shipping-destination {
display: none; }
```

Comment: The selector that worked for me was `#shipping_method +p.woocommerce-shipping-destination`

Answer (score 1):

Also you can try to hide it using custom CSS:

```
.woocommerce-shipping-destination {visibility: hidden;}
```

Comment: I've added the "display: none;" property to not only hide but remove the empty space previously occupied by that shipping text

Answer (score 1):

The shortest and easiest way would be:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_shipping_estimate_html', '__return_false' );
```

More info here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/__return_false/